# Unable to display dynamic data into column2 HTML layout and the alignment is look not good in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, forms

I have the below HTML file and trying to create two column layout using HTML and CSS and One column I wanna make it as REQUEST and other one is RESPONSE column. When I enter the value in text field in Column1 then It should return response in RESPONSE in column2.

**Style:**

```
<style>
*{
  box-sizing: border-box; 
 }

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 450px; 
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row:after{

  width: 900px;
}

.submitBtn
{
  margin: 10px;
}

input{
  align-self: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
#sbtbtn
{
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
}

</style>
```

**HTML (Body):**

```
 <div class="toolbar" role="banner">
      <img src="https://www.amazonlogo.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/AMZ_logo_h_100x26.png" alt="logo" />
      <span>Welcome</span>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="content" role="main">
      <!-- Highlight Card -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
          <h2>REQUEST</h2>
        <div>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="calId" placeholder="Enter CAL ID" class="user_id_text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="submitBtn">
          <input id="sbtbtn" type="submit" (click)="getById(calId)" value="submit"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
          <h2>RESPONSE</h2>
          <div id="table">
             <table width="100%" class="table">
               <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>Component Name</th>
                 <th>API Name</th>
                 <th>Error Message</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let binary of data">
                  <td>{{binary.componentName}}</td>
                  <td>{{binary.apiName}}</td>
                  <td>{{binary.errorMessage}}</td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

The above *.html will give below output:

Screenshot-1:

[image]

When I enter the value in to the text field and click submit button then It shows like below:

[image]

[image]

**Expected Result:**

**1. I just want to get two HTML column layout without background color.**

**2. I want the text field and submit button in the middle of column1 page.**

**3. The result should fit into the column2 page.**

**4. If the value increase there should be side bar in column2 and all the data should be display inside column2.**

I'm very new to web design. Can someone help me to achieve this?

Note: It's responsive page. And the design should work in all devices.

Comment: add your https://stackblitz.com/ if possible. This is angular related you have to component code to help you better.

Comment: Archana : Have you include bootstrap css to your html, It works fine for me whn I include `bootstrap version 4.3.1`

Comment: @Ajith - Can you share me the working code so that I can try.

Comment: Please link the follwing in your html <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">   No other change Ihave made

Comment: It returned 404 error code:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan Make sure href in link tag is https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css  Open in browser and copy the correct link and see it is working   ALso change `class="column"` to `class="column col-md-12 col-lg-6"`

Comment: can you please share the fiddle link. I just add the link tag but still see the same behavior. Is it possible to show the values inside only column2 instead of its displaying outside of the column2. Also not sure how to enable sidebar to scroll down the dynamic value. Still Its not resolve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204647/discussion-between-ajith-and-arrchanamohan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flex, instead of floats.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; //unnecessary, but if you want you can use it
 }

.column {
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
 }
```

This text overflow is probably caused by your table. Since your column if fed with more data than it can handle, your column is wider.

IMHO this could also be solved with flex, instead of using table.
Here is link to flex-box guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/